# How can I dissolve photography film?

Tags: acid-base, experimental-chemistry, solubility, home-experiment

I am looking to completely dissolve negative film strips. Acetone was my first try and did not work. If anyone knows/ or has any ideas i would be so greatful.

Comment: Consider what it is made of (plastic) and see what appropriate solvents are at your disposal or just set fire to it.

Comment: AFAIK, films were in last few decades made of acetylcelulose, with the active layer of gelatine. Useful link is https://www.researchgate.net/post/Solvent_for_Cellulose_Acetate

Comment: I am very surprised acetone did not work.